# OpenLayers 3 for consuming an INSPIRE WMS

Tags: wms, openlayers

I am just getting into OpenLayers3 (OL3) from a GIS background - I don't have much of a programming background.

I am trying to use INSPIRE WMS layers in an OL3 app (http://www.geostore.com/environment-agency/WebStore?xml=environment-agency/xml/inspireDataWms.xml)

I have used the tutorial below as a start and I can get that working but I can't get any INSPIRE WMS layers to work.

http://astuntechnology.github.io/osgis-ol3-leaflet/ol3/README.html

I am using QGIS for the GIS work and I have checked the WMS works in that fine.

Code for the layer I have tried:

```
var lyr_NationalParksEngland = new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
                      url: http://www.geostore.com/OGC/OGCInterface?UID%3DUDATAGOV2011%26PASSWORD%3Ddatagov2011%26INTERFACE%3DENVIRONMENT%26LC%3D400000000000000000,
                      params: {"LAYERS": "eainspire2011-wms-nationalparks_eng_inspire", "TILED": "true"},
                    })),
                    title: "National Parks (England)"
                  });
```

Comment: What projection is your map in?

Comment: I would be happy with any projection but 27700 is the aim and the other data I plan to use in 27700. I think I can use the example from OL3 examples as I won't be needing any on the fly re-projection http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/wms-custom-proj.html

Comment: But what did you set the map projection to in your code?

Comment: The astune tutorial is for 27700 but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: did you just post a username and password for a private service?

Comment: No! that would be silly. The service is from the environment agency listed in my original source

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://www.geostore.com/OGC/OGCInterface',
        params: {"SERVICE": "WMS",
                 "UID": "UDATAGOV2011",
                 "PASSWORD": "datagov2011",
                 "INTERFACE": "ENVIRONMENT",
                 "LC": "80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004038000007d0000000000",
                 "LAYERS": "eainspire2011-wms-sites_of_ssi_inspire", 
                 "Projection": 'EPSG:3857',
                 "TILED": "true"}
        })
      })
    ],
```

Comment: Not an INSPIRE WMS if it's using EPSG:3857